# Lifetime of a Google Apps script with no owner?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive, google-workspace

I have a Google Apps script that belonged to a former colleague. They have been offboarded and the script currently has No Owner. I am curious how long this GScript will exist without an owner assigned.

[image]

The user has been deleted since May and we have a backup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the fact that you can restore a user within the first 20 days of being deleted and a file can be restored within the first 25 days of being deleted (if the user still exist) I would say it will remain available 20 days. After that it will be permanently deleted and cannot be restored or transfer, I would suggest to make a copy of the file.

You can check these G Suite Administrator Help Center Articles to have more details about how Google manage deleted users and files.

1. [Restore a recently deleted user](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1397578?hl=en)
2. [Restore deleted files or shared drives](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7376096?hl=en)
3. [Restore a deleted user's Drive files](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2993112?hl=en)

UPDATE:

After checking the image well, I can see that the file is within a Shared Drive or "Team Drive" if that is the case according to "[Store & share files with shared drives](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7286514?hl=en)".

- Members of a shared drive share ownership of any files and folders.
- If someone leaves the shared drive, any files they added will stay.
- You can still share files with a link or invite.

That means if the user is deleted (leaves the share drive) the file added will stay, so it will be forever. And the Shared Drive cannot be deleted if contains files, if someone wants to delete the Shared Drive they must delete the files first.

Comment: The user was deleted in May, so definitely longer than 20 days.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to follow this up as I found a [bug on Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36756412) which shows that if a user is deleted while they own some scripts that are bound to Drive files, upon user deletion even if the Drive files are transferred to another user on the domain the owner doesn't change and the scripts can become inaccessable. Make sure that in the future all scripts are copied or saved in a shared Drive so that they can be accessed on user account deletion/migration.